# Jquery Find Next and Prev div Row id

Tags: jquery

> I want to find next div row id 
>   My Div Structure id

```
<div class="section row" id="row_1">
                    <div class="col-md-2"> <h6 class="fw400">Date</h6>
                        <label for="date_1" class="field prepend-icon">
                            <input type="text" id="date_1" name="date_1" class="gui-input" placeholder="Date" value="2017-02-18" readonly>
                            <label class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                            </label>
                        </label>
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="section row" id="row_2">
                    <div class="col-md-2"> <h6 class="fw400">Date</h6>
                        <label for="date_2" class="field prepend-icon">
                            <input type="text" id="date_2" name="date_2" class="gui-input" placeholder="Date" value="2017-02-18" readonly>
                            <label class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                            </label>
                        </label>
                    </div>
</div>
```

> When I clicked on first row of Input box(date_1) then that time i want to get next row div id which is "row_2" . I tried but i dont know how to get this. Can you just tell me how to do this??

Answer (score 1):

use [parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)  and [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$("#date_1").click(function(){

var id = $(this).parents().parents().next("div").attr("id");;
console.log(id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) method to get adjacent siblings. Later get the `id` attribute using [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

```js
$('.row').click(function() {
  console.log('Prev : ' + ($(this).prev().attr('id') || 'Not found'));
  console.log('Next : ' + ($(this).next().attr('id') || 'Not found'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section row" id="row_1">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <h6 class="fw400">Date</h6>
    <label for="date_1" class="field prepend-icon">
                            <input type="text" id="date_1" name="date_1" class="gui-input" placeholder="Date" value="2017-02-18" readonly>
                            <label class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                            </label>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="section row" id="row_2">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <h6 class="fw400">Date</h6>
    <label for="date_2" class="field prepend-icon">
                            <input type="text" id="date_2" name="date_2" class="gui-input" placeholder="Date" value="2017-02-18" readonly>
                            <label class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                            </label>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.section').click(function(){
    alert($(this).next('div').attr('id'));
  })
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76qabk1a/19/)

Answer (score 0):

Use parents and next.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/1rx3ydhu/)

```
$( "#date_1" ).focus(function() {
    var id = $(this).parents().parents().next('div').prop('id');
    alert(id);
});
```